# How to open an running activity with a notification action?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer, notifications

I want to open my timer app when i click on the notification. I have already tried the code below, but then it is just starting a new activity. I want to start the activity which is already running.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(timer.this, timer.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(timer.this, 0, intent, 0);

notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notification = new Notification.Builder(timer.this)
                       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                       .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                       .setContentTitle(clickedinterval)
                       .setContentText("Pause" +  " Time remaining: " + minutesPauseCountDown + ":" + secondsPauseCountDown)
                       .build();

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: a question regarding the coding- why are you keeping the java class name with small letters ?

Answer (score 0):

```
in your case use android:launchMode="singleInstance" in mainfest file 
Or 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK


<activity android:name=".Timer" android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:launchMode="singleTop" />
```

can also try

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Timer.this, Timer.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                PendingIntent pIntetn = PendingIntent.getActivity(timer.this, 0, intent, 0);

                notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notification = new Notification.Builder(timer.this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(pIntetn)
                        .setContentTitle(clickedinterval)
                        .setContentText("Pause" +  " Time remaining: " + minutesPauseCountDown + ":" + secondsPauseCountDown)
                        .build();

                notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

                notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: a question regarding the coding-  why are you keeping the java class name with small letters ? Sorry The question was for the main guy